# Prestashop access php variable in a js file which is hooked in header?

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I am creating a custom module in Prestashop. In that module I want to use my php variable inside the js file. How can I access the value in js file. I don't want to pass the variable to smarty file.
The js file is hooked in the header. So can someone tell me hw to pass the php value to external js file which is hooked in the header?

Any help and suggestion will be really appreciable. Thanks

Comment: for a single variable i would suggest passing it as a smarty variable, the only other way to get a variable from php is to make an ajax request to retrieve the variable which might be overkill

Comment: @defuzed thanks for the comment. But my js file is an external file I mean not inside my smarty file so how can I pass the value?

Answer (score 6):

Here's how to do it

```
Media::addJsDef('var_name', $variable);
// or
Media::addJsDef(array('var_name' => $variable));
```

Answer (score -1):

You're going to have to pass it through Smarty, even though you don't want to do it (why?). You module already hooks onto `displayHeader` hook, it's a matter of

```
public function hookDisplayHeader($params)
{
    $this->context->controller->addJS($this->getPathUri().'views/js/%your_js_file%.js');

    $this->context->smarty->assign('foo', 'bar');

    return $this->display(__FILE__, 'header.tpl');
}
```

Your `header.tpl` would look something like:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var foo = "{$foo|escape:'htmlall':'UTF-8'}";
</script>
```

And then in your javascript file you can use global `foo` variable.